# Problem in redirecting standard input and output

Tags: mysql, input, output, redirect

I want to take `backup` of my `mysql` data using `mysqldump`. I have three files containing names of mysql `tables` line by line. My script has this line -

```
mysqldump -h localhost -uroot --lock-tables=false db < $2 > ~/backup/$name'.sql'
```

I am using `getopts` to handle some `options`. So basically `$2` is the file I am going to provide. This file has - table1 and table2. So this command should only take backup of these two tables.

But when I `cat` the `~/backup/name.sql` file it shows all the backup of `db`. I am not sure if it is the combined backup of all the tables from all the 3 files or the whole db.
But it is taking backup of whole db instead of two tables.

What am I doing wrong?

It works fine when I put it like this -

```
mysqldump -h localhost -uroot --lock-tables=false db table1 table2 >  ~/backup/$name'.sql'
```

Comment: Should I have asked this question in http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it fails is that mysqldump does not read the standard input; table1 and table2 are (optional) arguments, but you are providing them not on the command line, but on stdin.

If `$2` is the filename of a file that contains one line with the text `table1 table2`, then the following should work:

```
mysqldump -h localhost -uroot --lock-tables=false db `cat $2` > ~/backup/$name'.sql'
```

Bash will expand this command line to

```
mysqldump -h localhost -uroot --lock-tables=false db table1 table2 > /home/user/backup/somename.sql
```

which is what you want to run.

However, since you are using getopt anyways, maybe you could put "table1" in `$2` and "table2" in `$3`, and run just

```
mysqldump -h localhost -uroot --lock-tables=false db $2 $3 > ~/backup/$name'.sql'
```

Comment: Thanks. great help. Don't mind me asking but should I have put this in http://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead of askubuntu. I mean these two are very alike.

Comment: I think yes, this is not Ubuntu specific.

Comment: yes. thanks. I have just asked it in Meta - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149833/how-do-i-decide-which-question-to-put-where

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on how your running the script but you should be able to use back-ticks and cat the file.

```
mysqldump -h localhost -uroot --lock-tables=false db `cat $2` > ~/backup/$name'.sql
```